# plotting surface z=x^2+y^2 in Mathematica

Tags: graphing-functions, surfaces, mathematica

This should be an elementary exercise but I cannot find the solution in any books or notes. Could someone show me how to plot $z=x^2+y^2$ first in Mathematica?
By hand?

And, how to outward normal to this surface, say at some point (-1, -2, 5)?

Many thanks!

Comment: `Plot3D[x^2+y^2,{x,-3,3},{y,-3,3}]` works.

Comment: I did try this, but how to include z here?

Comment: It automatically interprets $z=f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$, so the inclusion of $z$ is implicit.

Comment: sorry i modified and add the other part of my question.

Comment: You do realize that the point $(-3,2,1)$ is not on the surface?

Comment: modified again. Sorry of this huge omission!!!!

Comment: There's a [Mathematica specific SE site](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/). This might be more appropriate there, though it might be closed as a "Read the Manual" type question.

Comment: I know and I tried that initially, but I do not know what tag to put there.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this seems to work:

```
p1 = Plot3D[x^2 + y^2, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3},
   BoxRatios -> Automatic, Mesh -> False, 
   PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.4]];
f[x_, y_, z_] := z - x^2 - y^2;
grad[x_, y_, z_] = Grad[f[x, y, z], {x, y, z}];
normal[x_, y_, z_] = 
  Simplify[grad[x, y, z]/Sqrt[grad[x, y, z].grad[x, y, z]]];
MyPoint = {-1, -2, 5};
MyEndPoint = MyPoint + 5*normal[-1, -2, 5];
p2 = Graphics3D[Arrow[{MyPoint, MyEndPoint}]];
Show[p1, p2, ViewPoint -> {2.62, -1.78, 1.17}]
```

[image]

Not sure if you're wanting the arrow to go this way, or the opposite; if you want the opposite, then change

```
MyEndPoint=MyPoint+5*normal[-1,-2,5]
```

to

```
MyEndPoint=MyPoint-5*normal[-1,-2,5]
```

Might need to fiddle with viewpoint to get a good picture.

Comment: @Mark McClure: Thanks for the edit: very nice!

Answer (score 1):

You can also plot this surface with the commands

`f = z - x^2 - y^2;
 gr1 = ContourPlot3D[f == 0, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, {z, 0, 8}, 
   Mesh -> None, 
   ContourStyle -> 
    Directive[Green, Opacity[0.5], Specularity[White, 30]]];
 p0 = {-1, -2, 5};
 p = {x, y, z};
 n = Grad[f, p] /. Thread[p -> p0];
 gr2 = Graphics3D[{Red, Arrow[{p0, p0 - 0.5 n}]}];
 Show[gr1, gr2]`

[image]

NOTE

The gradient vector was sign changed and scaled for display purposes.

Comment: Thanks for the edit.

Comment: both answers are great! Unsure which to accept...